# Android doesn't find library even if it's inside lib folder

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `Tesseract` with Android, everything is fine: I compiled the source and I have the `.so` files ready. Every `.so` file is in a folder for the different architecture  and is correctly inserted in the APK file by Android Studio (If I open the `.apk` file i can see `lib/` folder with all the directories inside + the `.so` files inside them)

They are named `lept.so` and `tess.so` and in the code it uses

```
System.loadLibrary("lept");
System.loadLibrary("tess");
```

But when I launch the application I get this exception

```
1-02 16:01:20.824  16384-16384/x.x.x.ocrapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: x.x.x.ocrapp, PID: 16384
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/x.x.x.ocrapp-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/x.x.x.ocrapp-2]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
        at x.x.x.ocrapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Which says that it's unable to load `lept` library.

It seems like it searchs the library inside `libraryPath=/data/app-lib/x.x.x.ocrapp-2` `app-lib` folder, while mine is inside `lib` folder.

It doesn't work neither in emulator nor in real device. (Samsung Galaxy S4)

How can I fix this exception and let Android load the native library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
They are named lept.so and tess.so
```

Those are not standard names, as they lack the `lib` prefix.

```
System.loadLibrary("lept");
System.loadLibrary("tess");
```

This causes a search for `liblept.so` which is not the file you have.

Either give your library the standard name, or specify an actual file name *including the path where it ends up installed on the device* to System.load() rather than System.loadLibrary().